# Is there an online source of active flight plans?

Tags: datasets, flight-plans

Is there a way I can look up flight plans filed in the United States? I tracked an aircraft on Flightradar24 and I would like to be able to find it's flight plan in some sort of database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are looking for domestic flights in the US. The FAA database is not public.

You can use ADS-B tracking sites to look at the route. Remember instructions after takeoff (departure and transition) and before landing (transition and approach) are determined late and can be changed, depending on winds and other parameters.

E.g. on Flight Aware, for [JBU124](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/JBU124) between LAX and JFK, the route is mentioned:

[image]

and can be decoded:

[image]

These sites also create [route history records](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/JBU124). After a certain number of days, it's paying.

Comment: Data is not public. That's what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: In the US, flight plans don't go through the FAA at all, it is handled by LEIDOS, formerly Lockheed Martin Flight Services under federal contract.

Comment: @RonBeyer: Indeed FAA subcontracts to Leidos, Lockheed Martin... as many other. [services](http://news.lockheedmartin.com/2002-06-28-Lockheed-Martin-Awarded-FAA-Contract-to-Modernize-En-Route-Air-Traffic-Control-System?asPDF=1).  But the service is still a FAA one. Nasa does the same, the Shuttle is still a Nasa spacecraft.

Comment: The FAA has a great database. You should find what you are looking for. @mins you are right.

Comment: So FlightAware just infers based on location that it was using various VORs? Or does it somehow get the route ahead of time?

Comment: @aidanh010: The *planned route* you see comes from the flight plan (FlightAware has access to flight plans filed at ANSP like Eurocontrol or FAA), the *actual position* comes from multiples sources, ANSP but also [private ADS-B receivers](https://fr.flightaware.com/adsb/flightfeeder/) (including multilateration). FlightAware started providing tracking data by only sharing private ADS-B output between subscribers.