# Where are the planes going that fly west over Niagara Falls at night?

Tags: usa, flight-tracking

Where are the planes landing that fly over Niagara Falls, New York late at night heading in a western direction? And what altitude are they flying at? Between 10pm and 12am Wondering if they are going to Toronto ,Detroit or elsewhere . They are commercial flights I think . I did not realize the technical aspect of this site . I was just asking as a point of curiosity and could not find an answer elsewhere .

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Are you asking how to identify them (see [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/26491/62)), or have you already identified them but you want to know their flight plan (see [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/35693/62))? If those questions don't help, please give us as much extra information as possible, e.g. are these airliners or small propeller planes; do they always fly at the same times etc. You might also find the [tour] helpful if you're new to the site.

Comment: As explaine din the [help center](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you may rephrase your question to make it more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Go to [Flight Radar](https://www.flightradar24.com/airport/iag/arrivals) and you can click on the specific flights and see the plane type and where it is going.